# Microsoft Pointofservice fails to initialize if NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy is true

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, pos

I have seen many reports on this, but all the answers seem to be the opposite of the problem I'm encountering.  I have a custom DLL written in about 2011; it drives a set of custom payment devices, and has been running without issue for years (several thousand transactions a day).  Recently a department started testing new POS terminals, and the dll is now failing in the lab.

The dll is designed to run either as OPOS or POS.net (depending on the client app).  When running OPOS, there are no issues; regardless of setting it works fine.  When running POS.net, I get an exception at:

```
Public Function Open(ByRef DevName As String, UseEvent As Integer) As Integer
    DIM MyPOSExplorer As New PosExplorer()
```

> System.TypeinitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception.'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> PosLibraryException: Failed to open registry key

Now, this is where it gets confusing, well, to me.  For most of the answers I've seen on this issue, they recommend adding the following to the config:

```
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

However, if set to true, I get the failure above.  If set to *false*, **everything works perfectly** (for the DLL itself).

So, the answer might be, why not just set it to false and call it a day?  The parent application (off-the-shelf product) *requires* that the policy be set to True.  (*When running the application, False will allow the device to be claimed, and do successful reads - however, eventually the app has internal errors; when set to True, the app crashes on load when it hits initialization of the payment device*)

The DLL targets .Net 4.5; the computer systems are running 4.51 or higher.

What I'm trying to determine is, what to look for to understand why my setup seems to require the opposite of most of the suggested fixes out there.  And maybe that will lead me to how to reverse this problem.  (If I can get POS.net to work with 'True' and fail with 'False', I'd be happy.  This DLL has been twilighted; and will be retired within the next year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a set of machines running Microsoft.PointOfService.DLL version 1.12.xx.  When everything was moved to version 1.14.1.0, the issue went away.  All code is now running as expected with `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>`.